# Android: How to ask for only a subset of DEVICE_ADMIN permissions

Tags: android, permissions, admin

I got these two in my Manifest.xml:

```
<android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
<action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
```

Meta-data:

```
<meta-data
android:name="android.app.device_admin"
android:resource="@xml/device_owner_receiver"/>
```

And this in my MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Click");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

This works nicely, but in the Activity where the user should grant admin rights, the system lists a lot of things I don't want to do, like "Erase all data". Can I ask for only a subset of the admin rights, like "Lock Screen"?

Thanks.

Comment: You should have a `<meta-data>` element in your manifest, with a name of `android.app.device_admin`, pointing to an XML resource listing the specific policies that you want. Do you have this element? If so, edit your question and post the contents of that XML resource.

Comment: Perfect, this is the answer, the referenced xml is selfexplanatory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<receiver>` element for your subclass of `DeviceAdminReceiver` should have a `<meta-data>` element, with a name of `android.app.device_admin`. This will point to an XML resource, listing the specific policies that you want. My interpretation of your question and comment is that you started with a resource that listed a bunch of policies, such as:

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-policies>
    <limit-password />
    <watch-login />
    <reset-password />
    <force-lock />
    <wipe-data />
    <expire-password />
    <encrypted-storage />
    <disable-camera />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

You can trim back the list to just the policies that you need. Anything else will be unavailable to you, even if the user makes your app be a device administrator.
Unfortunately, the roster of possible XML elements seems to be undocumented at the present time.